# Ports opened on Ubuntu close themselves after a while

Tags: networking, localhost

I want to open some local ports on Ubuntu in zcash full node regtest mode to do some experiments.

But I encountered a problem where I successfully opened a few local ports and in zcash cli the corresponding nodes are also connected, but after a while the ports just closed themselves and therefore the nodes also disconnected later.

Opening some local ports (18444, 18445, 18446):

[image: Opening some local ports(18444,18445,18446)]

The ports I opened closed themselves after a while.

[image: The ports I opened closed themselves after a while]

And I checked, my firewall on Ubuntu is not active.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a problem with the system?  Check `/var/log/syslog` and see if you have any notices from `oom-killer` killing the processes unexpectedly.

Comment: ok, I'll check it thanks~